# AVFoundation Camera Preview Wrong Orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, avfoundation

I'm making a custom camera with a small preview area inside of the iPad, however, the stream in that previewing is rotated clockwise.

I have looked at both AVCam demo and the SquareCam demo on Apple and I don't see a solution in either. All of the AVFoundation orientation threads on StackOverflow are talking specifically about output orientation, not input orientation.

Here is the session code I'm using:

```
AVCaptureDevice *frontalCamera = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    _session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [_session beginConfiguration];
    NSError *error;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:frontalCamera error:&error];
    [_session addInput:input];
    _output = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    [_output setOutputSettings:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG,AVVideoCodecKey,nil]];
    [_session addOutput:_output];
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_session];
    previewLayer.frame = self.imageViewCamera.bounds;
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [self.imageViewCamera.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
    _session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;
    [_session commitConfiguration];
    [_session startRunning];
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The layer’s orientation. (Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Use [videoOrientation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureConnection/videoOrientation)
>   (AVCaptureConnection) instead.)

so use:

```
[[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer connection] setVideoOrientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

or

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation= AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
```

Answer (score 2):

The Apple docs for iOS 6 say to use `videoOrientation (AVCaptureConnection)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This has been deprecated but you can change the orientation of your previewLayer counter-clockwise.

```
previewLayer.orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
```

I'm not sure what the non-deprecated solution is though.

Comment: That worked but I would like a non-depricated solution. This will do for now, thanks!